# getting an image from the web browser and edit in the application

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

i want to get an image form the default web browser and edit that image in my application i have searched a lot on many different forums regarding this but i was unable to find a solid answer to that. I am rather confused that whether it is possible or not. kindly, help me out regarding this matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for by "getting an image from the default web browser", but the simplest way to do this would probably be to build your app to respond to a [share action](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) from the browser, analyse the URL that is being shared and load that URL in your app. If the URL doesn't point to an image resource, handle the error gracefully.